# Multiple validations in one cell

Tags: data-validation

I am trying to creat a validation that says the date can only be today() + or -7 AND it can not be a weekend.  I have gotten the two parts to work seperaTELY but not together.  I do not seem to be able to layer one validation on top of the other and I can not figure out how to combine them into one.

I have a validation of date between TODAY()-7 and TODAY()+7
and I have one
=AND(weekdayA1<>1,WeekdayA1<>7).

ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Like Mike said, just separate every condition that must be true by a comma. This checks the date range, then checks if it's a weekday. You get a result of TRUE or FALSE.

```
=AND(AND(A1>=TODAY()-7,A1<=TODAY()+7,WEEKDAY(A1)<>1,WEEKDAY(A1)<>7))
```

If you want to return text or another value based on your date validation, replace the first AND with an IF

```
=IF(AND(A1>=TODAY()-7,A1<=TODAY()+7,WEEKDAY(A1)<>1,WEEKDAY(A1)<>7),"YES","NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest multiple `AND` functions:

```
=AND(AND(condition1, condition2), condition3)
```

**Edit:**

I was thinking of nested `IF` statements when I wrote this. `AND` *can* be nested but it also supports multiple inputs, so the following is perfectly acceptable:

```
AND(condition1, condition2, condition3)
```

The result will only be TRUE if all three conditions are TRUE.